# Angular 2 *ngFor not working as intended even when CommonModule imported

Tags: javascript, angular

I have one feature module that I created via CLI, so it imports the common module.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

But when I do this normal paragraph appears but paragraph with *ngFor part doesn't work, it does not display anything.

```
<p> Some normal paragraph </p>    
<p *ngFor = "let i of [1,2,3]" >home works!</p>
```

I also tried to create a shared module, import and export the common module there, and import that shared module in my feature module but it didn't work.

What could cause the problem?

Comment: I have no idea but it started to work somehow. But I left this maybe someone has the same issue and as I understand it is not good to delete questions here.

Comment: Sometimes u need to do npm run again and magically all works :D

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced that problem. after looking at my app.module.ts I found that shared my custom module is not imported there. After importing it in app module my problem has been solved